# How to insert variables into python when using PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

So I'm sure there is already a solution out there for my question but I haven't been able to see an answer that helps me understand it clearly.

I want to use a function that takes in a variable and uses that variable in a PostgreSQL select statement.

This is my attempt which is incorrect.

```
def some_func(var):
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE attribute = %s",var)
    return
```

So if I am to run some_func("height"), I want the postgres statement to be executed as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE attribute = 'height';
```

I got the error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: Did you do `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE attribute = %s" % var)`? Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Ok so it was my mistake, it's not a syntax error, the error I got was "TypeError: not all arguements converted during string formatting", my apologies

Comment: Yeah, see my first comment for how it should be formatted, if you weren't already aware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the documentation](http://psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.execute)

> Parameters may be provided as sequence or mapping and will be bound to variables in the operation.

Place the variable in a sequence:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE attribute = %s", [var])
```

Read also [Passing parameters to SQL queries.](http://psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#query-parameters)

Answer (score -1):

When **string formatting**, don't use a **comma**, but another **percentage**. In your case, this would be:

```py
def some_func(var):
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE attribute = %s" % var)
    return
```

This should achieve what you are aiming for, if not please comment!

Comment: [Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint.](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters) (because of [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)).

Comment: I'm not familiar with SQL and such, haha! How about f-strings? I can edit my answer if that's the case :p

Comment: format() and f-strings are also vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: What would be the solution then? Create some variable with what you want to do beforehand? Like `x = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE attribute = %s" % var`, then `cursor.execute(x)`? I assume your answer is viable, so I was just interested in any other ways. Might be helpful if I ever need to use SQL etc. (:

Comment: The subject is too broad for a single comment. The best and simplest way is to use specialized methods like `cursor.execute()`, avoiding building SQL queries outside of these methods. All reliable SQL libraries (not only in Python) have this kind of methods or functions.